# phpPgAdmin refused to connect

Tags: php, postgresql, ubuntu, phppgadmin

I have Ubuntu 18, php 7.4 and trying to install phpPgAdmin. I did all steps from this instruction: https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-phppgadmin-on-ubuntu-18-04/

My /etc/hosts file:

```
#127.0.0.1  localhost
#127.0.1.1  site-1.loc
127.0.0.2   site-2.loc



# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

In the address http://127.0.0.1/phppgadmin/ I see just text "127.0.0.1 refused to connect."

[image]

Any ideas how to fix phpPgAdmin connection?

UPD:

```
❯ systemctl status apache2
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-03-22 12:08:41 EET; 47min ago
  Process: 905 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 911 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 921 (apache2)
    Tasks: 11 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─ 921 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─ 922 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─ 923 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─ 924 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─ 925 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─ 926 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─1019 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─1020 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─1491 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─1495 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─1496 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

бер 22 12:08:41 dell systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
бер 22 12:08:41 dell apachectl[911]: [Tue Mar 22 12:08:41.434563 2022] [alias:warn] [pid 915] AH00671: The Alias directive in /etc/apache2/sites-enabl
бер 22 12:08:41 dell apachectl[911]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.88.211. Se
бер 22 12:08:41 dell systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
❯
```

```
❯ service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2022-03-22 12:06:38 EET; 51min ago
  Process: 610 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 610 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

бер 22 12:06:38 dell systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
бер 22 12:06:38 dell systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

Comment: Why did you tagged `php` ?

Comment: What is the ouput of `systemctl status apache2` and `service postgresql status`

Comment: In the `/etc/hosts` file, `127.0.0.1` is a comment

Comment: @executable I've updated information in the question

Comment: Can you try to access http://192.168.88.211/phppgadmin/

Comment: @executable the same issue: 192.168.88.211 refused to connect.